# Add lat lon coords to mini map leaflet rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

How to correctly implement lat/lon coordinates to a minimap, because I want the minimap to display at the location provided by each marker. It will open after clicking on the marker, however, I notice that if I click on one marker the minimap opens, however, when I click on another marker, the minimap does not change location. Therefore, how can I have it centre to the location of each marker on each click?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map')
)
list_of_inputs <- c()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    latitude <- c(53.380909, 53.371566)
    longitude <- c(-1.486197, -1.577604)
    placeNames <- c("Hicks Building", "The Sportsman")
    leaflet(options=leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>%
      setView(lng = -1.525, lat = 53.38, zoom =12) %>%
      addProviderTiles(provider = leaflet.providers::providers_default()$providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>%
      addMarkers(lat = latitude,
                 lng = longitude,
                 popup = placeNames)
    })
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    click = input$map_marker_click
    leafletProxy('map')%>%addMiniMap(zoomLevelFixed = 14, centerFixed = c(click$lat, click$lng))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems intuitively correct but as already proposed, it seems that the minimap is not being correctly refreshed. It might not be the intended behaviour for your particular use case, but one option is to **not** use the `centerFixed` parameter and simply use `setView` to recenter the map on the selected marker (and by extension the minimap).

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map')
)
list_of_inputs <- c()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    latitude <- c(53.380909, 53.371566)
    longitude <- c(-1.486197, -1.577604)
    placeNames <- c("Hicks Building", "The Sportsman")
    leaflet(options=leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>%
      setView(lng = -1.525, lat = 53.38, zoom =12) %>%
      addProviderTiles(provider = leaflet.providers::providers_default()$providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>%
      addMarkers(lat = latitude,
                 lng = longitude,
                 popup = placeNames)
  })
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    click = input$map_marker_click
    leafletProxy('map')%>%
      setView(lat = click$lat,
              lng = click$lng, 
              zoom = 12) %>% 
      addMiniMap(zoomLevelFixed = 14)    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This closely resembles my intention, although not exactly what I wanted, I will mark this as my answer because it's close to what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug to me. If you look at the development console, you will see that the second click issues an error:

> ```
> VM47:9 Uncaught TypeError: this.minimap.removeFrom is not a function
>     at e.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:9:22)
>     at LeafletWidget.methods.addMiniMap (<anonymous>:42:8)
>     at e.<anonymous> (leaflet.js:841:54)
>     at e.value (shinyapp.ts:724:29)
>     at e.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:819:16)
>     at e.value (shinyapp.ts:724:29)
>     at e.value (shinyapp.ts:707:12)
>     at i.onmessage (shinyapp.ts:353:15)
> ```

So it seems that the click tries to remove the `minimap` via `removeFrom` but for whatever reason this does not work. Maybe you [want to file a bug report](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/new)?